# How to nest knit calls to fix duplicate chunk label errors?

Tags: r, knitr

I'm running into a duplicate label error when I call a function that uses `knit` inside a `knit` call. If I label the chunks the problem goes away. Is there a way to call `some_function` in a way that doesn't collide with the parent `knit` call?

````
library(knitr)
some_function <- function(){
    knit(text ="
    ```{r }
        1
    ```
    ")
}
cat(knit(text ="
```{r }
    some_function()   
```
```{r }
    some_function()   
```
"))
````

Output:

````
```r
some_function()
```

```
## Error: duplicate label 'unnamed-chunk-1'
```
````

Comment: why not to name just the chnuk with some_function?

Comment: I'd have to make sure the chunk label was unique every time I called some_function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `knit_child()` instead of `knit()` in `some_function()`:

````
library(knitr)
some_function <- function(){
  knit_child(text ="
    ```{r }
        1
    ```
    ")
}
cat(knit(text ="
```{r }
    some_function()   
```
```{r }
    some_function()   
```
"))
````

Comment: Thanks a lot @Yihui ! If I understood the `knit` code correctly, setting the child mode ensures that no object gets written to the `.knitEnv`, which is what was messing me up. Correct?

Comment: `knit()` will initialize some internal objects, including the object to manage code chunks, and `knit_child()` will not; if that object is initialized again, knitr will start counting chunks from 1 again, leading to the chunks with the same label `unnamed-chunk-1` in two nested `knit()` calls and they will clash

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly the context use of your code. Why not to use simply knitr child document feature?

Here a workaround ( hope that someone else come with a better solution specially you if you give more context)

````
some_function <- function(chunk.name='chunk1'){
  knit(text =sprintf("
    ```{r %s}
        1
    ```
    ",chunk.name))
}
cat(knit(text ="
```{r }
    some_function('a1')   
```
```{r }
    some_function('a2')   
```
"))
````